# YAML::load() *** TypeError Exception: wrong argument type NMatrix (expected Data)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, ruby-on-rails-5, data-mining

As I issued [here](https://github.com/gbuesing/kmeans-clusterer/issues/2), I am trying to store/restore an object into/from the database, I have the following snap:

```
kmeans = KMeansClusterer.run(k, colours, runs: AppConfig.fabric.colours.cluster.runs)

kmeans.predict [[1, 2, 3]]     # <- works fine 

(YAML::load(YAML::dump(kmeans))).predict [[1, 2, 3]] # <- ERROR
```

When I am trying to dump/load the object with YAML, I get the following error

> **ERROR:** **** TypeError Exception: wrong argument type NMatrix (expected Data)*

**Question:** How can I store/restore the `kmeans` object without any trouble?

Comment: Normally for dumping and restoring I would recommend [`Marshal`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Marshal.html) just make sure to pay attention to the *"Security Concerns"* section. `::dump` will return a `String` nice for storing in the database

Comment: @engineersmnky I've tried to use `Marshal` but it gives me the `*** TypeError Exception: no _dump_data is defined for class NMatrix` error which from its look I don't think this is fixable.

Comment: while it is fixable it would definitely be difficult and possibly fragile. Sorry I couldn't be more help

Answer (score 0):

Serialization needs cooperation of the objects.

NMatrix does not appear to support serialization.